# how to implement multi layer Div in css?

Tags: html, tags, division

I want to implement the picture with 4 Division
I use z-index but i fall into a loop , it means that i cant implement the last layer, because it should be both bigger and smaller than a layer!

At first there are 4 divs , 2 vertical and 2 horizontal , and these are apart , after scroll the browser the vertical dives , move and the structure that you can see in pic appear

my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="height:100000px">



  
   <div style=" position:fixed; background-color: #468813; height:45px; width:200px; position: absolute
    ; margin:200px 0; z-index:3  "> 3</div>

    <div style=" position:fixed; background-color: #AADD02 ;height:200px; width:50px ;position:fixed
 ; margin: 0 20px; z-index:3  "> 4</div>

    <div style=" position:fixed; background-color: #468813;height:45px; width:200px ;position: absolute
         ; margin:280px 0 ;  z-index:4 "> 4</div>

          <div style=" position:fixed; background-color: #AADD02;height:200px; width:50px ;position:fixed
   ; margin: 0 110px ; z-index:2  "> 1</div>

</body>
</html>
```

picture :

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/2rzqcet.jpg]

Comment: share your code please

Comment: @akash , i add code to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Have seen your code as well as your picture with it. The picture you have attached won't be possible with 4 divs.
Its better to use 8 divs and then arrange it according to the layout you want by the help of - z-index.
By the help of proper css you will be able to do.
GOOD LUCK

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible with 4 divs as div is not "bendable" as a paper (and can't have 2 different z-index you will need in this case).

You will simply need to use 8 divs and you will get the result you want.

Comment: At first there are 4 divs , 2 vertical and 2 horizontal  , and these are apart
, after scroll the browser the vertical dives , move and the structure that you can see in pic appear....

Comment: What I meant is that you can take each div and split it to 2 divs one next to the other and give each part a different z order. With 4 divs it is just impossible.